# PHP Mysqli_real_escape_string in function expects parameter to be 1. Null given

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a mysql function to escape strings.  I continue to be plagued with a never ending error.  The feed spits out:

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/shipstud/public_html/post_auth.php on line 39.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.  I've attached the relevant code below:

```
//connect to server and database
$db=mysqli_connect('***','***','***','***');

// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connect failed";
    exit();
}



//parameter checking
$username = safe(stripslashes(trim($_POST['username'])));


//sanitize input parameters
function safe($value)
{
    $secureString = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);

   return $secureString;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't imported the $db variable into the function's [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
function safe($value)
{
   global $db;

   $secureString = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);

   return $secureString;
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the variable as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

the `$db` variable is not in scope in `safe()`. Try:

```
$username = safe($db, stripslashes(trim($_POST['username'])));

function safe($db, $value)
{
    $secureString = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);

   return $secureString;
}
```

Or perhaps cleaner:

```
function safe($db, $value)
{
    $secureString = $db->real_escape_string($value);

   return $secureString;
}
```